# ASP.net Error in Design Mode

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-express, visual-web-developer

I just switched to VS 2010, and upgraded a previous project. I'm getting the following error on a page in design mode for 2 controls:

```
Error Creating Control - ObjectName 
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

One of them is a simple label, and the other is a ajax update panel. Other pages look fine. When I build and test the app, the page renders fine in the browser and functions fine - the label functions as expected and the content in the update panel works as expected.

Any ideas why I'm getting this error? I tried some of the google results to no avail. It'd be great to get this out of the way.

Thanks!

Comment: I think so, I have runat="server" set on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error can occur when the Designer in Visual Studio instantiates an instance of a server control or composite control.  It will attempt to read readable properties that may map to objects inside your control that have yet to be initialized.  If you have a custom server control you need to override the [CreateChildControls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.createchildcontrols.aspx) method of the base Control calls and inside it initialize any objects your properties depend on and then in the properties call the base [EnsureChildControls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.ensurechildcontrols.aspx) method.

This will ensure that all of the dependent objects in your control are initialized before they're referenced.

Comment: Hmm - any ideas why I'm getting it on this label: <asp:Literal id="AssessType" runat="server" Text="Self"/>

I'm using built in tools - Ajax update panel, etc., and the one custom control I have on the page displays fine on another page when viewed in the designer.

This is a bit confusing, because I looked at it in VS 2008 on another machine, and it displays fine.

I think it might be something trivial I might be overlooking - I didn't change the page from when it displayed fine. Maybe VS 2010 has stricter standards?